# Stock Exchanges with only 6 price changes a day?

Tags: economy, trade

I am trying to write a world economy system for a utopia.

Can a worldwide stock exchange with only 6 price changes every day work? i.e. people can only sell or buy n-stocks every 6 hours, compared to price changes every 10ms as happens in our world?

You could queue a transaction to happen at the next exchange, and on the tock of the hour all the trades would go through.

The number 6 is so that it's on equal playing fields for people around the planet with different day and night times. Because a market works better if apples, oranges and iron and everything changes less than 10,000 times per day, in a humanly recognizable time.

Comment: Well, how long would the stock exchange be opened every 6 hours? Or do you imagine it more along the lines of people placing bids/offers, etc. the whole time and every 6 hours the exchange magically works through all the bids/offers at the same instant?

Comment: I feel like there would be a shadow price to stocks. People trading would exchange their queues, and a shadow authority would estimate the upcoming prices. People would then trade based on the inbetween of this window (something like how calls and puts came about). Capitalism finds a way.

Comment: @comprehensible so, how do you decide which transactions are conducted first? You need a way to pair up bids and offers, etc.

Comment: Does a market work better if the price of oranges, apples and iron changes 5000 time every day, or if it changes 6 times a day? Good point dot spot. I'm trying to find a solution whereby a market becomes panicked if it changes 5000 times per day.

Comment: And now to the big $$$ question... how would prices be set in this system? Imagine that some news is driving prices sharply high or low... who would decide the price for the new session? Prices currently are set by agreements of buyers and sellers, if prices cannot change then a side might believe that the price does not reflect the value and prevent the sale; which in turn will make still more difficult to "tune" the official prices...

Comment: @NexTerren, that is exactly what would happen.  People would also do side trades during the 4 hours between openings that would then be realized at "stock time."

Comment: @NexTerren a slight modification: since trade has been around forever, but capitalism is only a few hundred years old, "*the market* finds a way".

Comment: If your goal is to forbid algorithmic trading there are better solutions which don't run into unsolvable problems for price setting. Require that each buy or sell offer remain valid for at least 5 minutes; put a small tax on transactions (0.01% works wonders); etc.

Comment: Is it 6 times a day (every 4 hours) or every 6 hours (4 times a day) ? Or is your day 36h ? :p

Comment: *"Can a worldwide stock exchange with only 6 price changes every day work? i.e. people can only sell or buy n-stocks every 6 hours,"* As Keelhaul pointed out, six price changes a day doesn't equal buying or selling 6 times a day. *"compared to price changes every 10ms as happens in our world?"* Prices don't change every 10 ms in our world. Prices do change in response to buyer/seller matching, and will only change when there is such a match. If you are going to reinvent the stock market, at least please first learn how it actually works in the real world. [money.se] might be a place to start.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling in regular situations I would agree with you. But if there is some new information that means a sudden change of value (or expectations) how would it be solved? Imagine that there is a report that orange production is going to be very bad this year, then frozen orange juice value would go through the ceiling. How and by who will the new price be set?

Comment: @SJuan76 Presumably by sellers raising their ask price in response to the report. As long as buyers only offer the previous bid price, no transactions will occur; when the buyers raise their bid price, transactions will again go through because there will be a match, and a new price point is established. Price, or perceived value, is irrelevant if nobody is willing to match your offer. I can ask \$100 for a cob of corn that I want to sell, but if buyers are only willing to pay (bid) \$1 for the same item, then the *proper* price is most likely somewhere in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Maybe, maybe not, but it probably won't get much use.

Stock exchanges are private enterprises, not government controlled. If your stock exchange runs only 6 times a day perhaps people would list their companies on one that runs 12 times a day, or constantly 24/7. Perhaps they wouldn't officially list at all and you'd get a black market for share trading.

To the people who initially sell the shares to the exchange, it doesn't matter, they just need to sell the shares to raise finance, they'll sell where they think they'll get the best price. The most investment for their company, after that the price is just an indicator of how well the company is doing.

Flash crashes and flash spikes only affect the people who play in HFT. If you research a company, see that it has a solid product, a solid chance to make a good profit and increase its value, then you buy at what you think it's worth and you keep it as a long term investment. HFT fluctuations don't bother you.

## If you regulate the market to 6 trades a day, is it utopia?

Perhaps it would be simpler to just prevent the use of automated trading. Everything must be done with physical handshake between two people. If you're in New York and want to buy in London, you phone your dealer and tell him what to buy, the dealer then shouts across the room to anyone who might be selling. They shake hands and the deal is done. No more HFT, but does it really matter?

Answer (score 7):

It would fail as fast as any utopia can fail.

A discontinuity like that is not beneficial.  In fact, it can be downright disastrous.

From the sound of it, you want trades within each epoch to all occur at the same price.  Thus, if the price of a stock is $1, and I buy 10 shares (presumably finding a seller), it doesn't change the stock price, it merely decreases the number of shares for sale on the market at that time.  You've engaged in price fixing.  As a result, you could easily reach a situation where there are simply no sellers or no buyers because the fixed price is too far from the actual value people attribute to the stock.

Then, at the end of the epoch, all trades go through and we need to set a new price.  But what do we set it to?  If there were more sellers than buyers, we should clearly reduce the price.  But do we reduce it to \$.99?  \$90?  \$0.50?  \$0.01?  We don't really have any useful information to set the price.

Alternatively, we permit people to decide what price they are willing to buy/sell the shares, and then they all get to act at the end of the epoch.  If there was a buyer/seller match, then the sale goes through.  Otherwise, after 6 hours, the market announces to you that you didn't actually buy/sell your stock.  But how do you pair them up?  Algorithms will be subject to abuse, and lots of simple algortihms simply don't work.  You can't use any of the simple first-come-first-serve matching algorithms because that will instantly turn your market into an unofficial continuous shadow market with an official sweep every 6 hours.

In the end, you'd need the special kind of utopia where nobody questions why things are done the way they're done.  Otherwise, you'll eventually have someone realize that the system has been made inefficient, and they'll invent a more efficient one.

Comment: In our markets, some commodities trade 24/7 and some trade only in office hours, until the hammer falls. That is already inefficient because it causes panic and confusion in the pace of trading. If the trades were only open for 10 minutes every 4 hours, that would be as efficient as the current stock market? Our stock market is inefficient because it dates from the paper bonds age and newspapers, and it functions on optical fiber speeds = timing problems for all the world's trade.

Comment: @comprehensibe efficient inefficiency

Comment: @comprehensible *"Our stock market is inefficient"* Citation needed.

Comment: I could see very rational reasons why the government might do that; not least, to level the playing field between the pro and citizen investor.  The stock market is a positive-sum game; but *rapid trading* is a zero-sum game. So sophisticated millisecond trading with well-connected "bots" *definitely is* stealing from the less sophisticated. It's the kind of thing I could see even Europe disallowing for that reason. Anyway, **this is already a thing** - mutual funds can only be traded once per day.  It hasn't demolished mutual funds; they've become very successful.

Comment: @Harper Of course, those mutual funds are then built upon a stock system that is exchanging in real time.

Comment: @Curt a useless fact to the person trying to buy or sell the index fund at opportune market moments. That's the point, such a scheme would abolish market moments and make people plan their purchases and sales a little more carefully. You seem to think trade itself would fail without daytraders; I think they are leeches and people will figure out how to trade within the rules.  We always have.  the market is only open 6-1/2 hours a day 5 days, and we somehow muddle through.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling "Our stock market is inefficient", When a bank manager can buy 7 private aeroplanes and private groups spend 200 million USD for distant underground optical lines in between two exchange centers to take advantage of microsecond details between stock communication links, and they design advanced algorythms to hide stock sales and scatter them randomly over time, i'd say all aspects of timing and proportion of stock market mechanisms are distorted by races in communication technologies, which will only stop when they calculat the fastest optical pathways to out-time each other.

Comment: @comprehensible The challenge is how to undo those distortions without contorting the market even further.  I have heard of one argument that all trades should be given a random latency of a few milliseconds to undo the progress you mention.  That technique stands a better chance of working because it still keeps the market fluid.

Comment: Also, do remember that money is a strange thing once you get above "mere mortal" scales.  It doesn't do the things you think it should do.  National-scale money and the velocity it moves at is really hard to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.

It would require international legislation and agreement between countries but absolutely it could happen.

There are people who sit watching upticks and downticks all day, devise algorithms, front run etc.  All those useless jobs and industries that add nothing to humanity would be redundant.  It would be too risky to input highly leveraged trades as 6 trades times per day, another useless occupation gone.

Great idea, maybe we need to talk to our politicians!  The big barrier of course will be agreement, all countries must sign up and would London/ New York like to lose all that fast money?